# How long does it take for I'll Handle It hat to be awarded?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

The criteria for the [I’ll Handle It](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/ill-handle-it) hat is as follows:

> vote to close a question, edit it from closed, vote to reopen

I've voted to close a question, edited it from closed and voted to reopen it. The question is reopened 5 hours ago, but the hat is still not awarded. Revisions can be found [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/26997/revisions).

How long does it take for this hat to be awarded since it's already been ~5 hours? Is there a bug or is there some additional criteria?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the timeline for that question, you voted to reopen the question before you made your edit, but that is not the correct order of events you need to complete for the hat. Essentially:

- Vote to close the question, and wait for the question to be closed;
- *Then* edit the question;
- *Then* vote to reopen the question within an hour of the edit being made, and wait for the question to be reopened.

An edit to the question *after* casting your reopen vote does not count.

As an aside, I'm not sure why the "vote to reopen within an hour" part was added to the query. It might have been a lazy way of making sure the question didn't go through an entirely new close/reopen cycle after your edit? *shrugs*

Answer (score 3):

*Fairly* quickly - was a few minutes, though meeting the criteria was hard. I found a dupe, managed to dedupe it without changing the context in edits, improved and reopened.

Almost certain the only way to get this without a closehammer is cheating;